# Seaborn plots, legend overlaps figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Using Seaborn, my legend keeps overlapping the data, no matter what dataframe I use, or whether I use pairplots or jointgrids. I know I can work around this by removing Seaborn's legend and making a custom legend, however, that's not the "cleanest" route. How can I get Seaborn to create non-overlapping legends ?

Here some code:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, kind="reg", plot_kws={"marker": "+"}, hue="experiment", palette="Set2", x_vars=["alpha [%]", "shelter [%]", "beta [%]"], y_vars=["final [%]"])

plt.show()
```

(btw I'm on Mac OS, Pycharm,[image] Python 3.6seaborn 0.10.0 and matplotlib 3.3.3)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code provided. Can you confirm this is the entirety of the code? Otherwise, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can not do it with `pairplot`. [In the docs they say](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot):

> This is a high-level interface for `PairGrid` that is intended to make it easy to draw a few common styles. You should use `PairGrid` directly if you need more flexibility.

Taking [this `PairGrid` example from the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid), you can pass the `loc` parameter to the `add_legend()` method.

```py
g = sns.PairGrid(penguins, hue="species")
g.map_diag(sns.histplot)
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
g.add_legend(loc=(0.9,0.2))  # or g.add_legend(loc="upper right");
plt.show()
```

The arguments you can pass to the `loc` parameter are listed in the [Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend).